# trouble importing android-remote-stacktrace

Tags: android, stack-trace

I am trying to get a remote stacktrace on a crash, and so I'm trying to use [android-remote-stacktrace](http://code.google.com/p/android-remote-stacktrace/).  In eclipse, I imported it and added it to my build path, but I am getting this error:

```
07-09 20:54:32.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nullwire.trace.ExceptionHandler
```

This is odd, because I see trace.jar in my "Reference Libraries" and I see this class in there [which you can see in this screenshot of my Eclipse window](http://www.flickr.com/photos/gnychis/7539696150/in/photostream).

Is there something I am missing?  [Here is the code calling this class](https://github.com/gnychis/phone-activity/blob/master/src/com/gnychis/PhoneActivity/ActivityService.java#L109), I'm linking to github so that you can see that this is used in a Service.  Is it because "this" refers to a service rather than an Activity?

Answer (score 3):

You can create folder `libs` inside your project folder (if there is no one). Put your `trace.jar` in `libs`.